# What happens when list has no empty values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the following query to retrieve the first empty value from a list of *Integer* values. It is an ID column.

The column is filled with data from past years. The values have not been inserted by a primary key constraint, so gaps are in the list.

Query to get the first empty value from the list:

```
SELECT top(1) h.HistoryID + 1
FROM History h
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM History h2
                  WHERE h.HistoryID + 1 = h2.HistoryID)
ORDER BY h.HistoryID
```

As long as the list has a value to return (a gap), everything will work fine.

**Question 1**: what will happen when the list has no gaps anymore. What will this query return?

**Question 2**: how can the query be changed so that after all the **gaps** are returned, the first value at the end of the list is returned?

*Example*: [1,3,4]. The query will return **2** as first result. But then when the query runs again, is it possible to return **5**, again **6**,...?

Comment: Have you done any tests? Create the table, insert value 1 and value 3. Execute the query - what happened? Execute it again, etc.

Comment: I have done it on a Azure SQL Server / database, not locally. The thing is that I can not create a new table (Azure SQL Database) to test this with a small list. Also I do not have the installed programs on my device to do it locally.

Comment: You can use http://sqlfiddle.com to run some basic tests.

Comment: You can do some experiments on www.rextester.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Did not know those. Will test right away.

Comment: You want to all gaps items. Why don't you remove `top(1)`, you will have all items. `max(historyId)` always appears in this list.

Comment: I want one gap at the time. So the `TOP(1)` is needed. Overtime all the gaps will be filled. At that point I want the current **max ID** + 1.

Comment: when all gaps were filled, you always get `maxId + 1` with your query.

Comment: Thanks that was the main question I had. I am testing it right now to be sure. When the test is positive, I can implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the query on this tool: [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

The given query in the question section of this post will indeed return **max ID + 1** when there are no gaps anymore in the list.

**Example test 1**:

```
CREATE TABLE History ([HistoryID] int);

INSERT INTO History ([HistoryID]) VALUES(1), (3), (4);
```

The query will return:

> 2

**Example test 2**:

```
CREATE TABLE History ([HistoryID] int);

INSERT INTO History ([HistoryID]) VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4);
```

The query will return:

> 5

*Thanks for the feedback and help to the users who commented on my question*